# printing a specific variable of an object

Tags: java, object, constructor

This is probably a bad question, but i have constructed a DVD object in java:

```
DVD myDVD = new DVD (11.17 , 9 , 120 , " Howl ’s Moving Castle " , " Hayao Miyazaki " );
```

I have a toString to print the whole object, but I've been asked to print the director (Hayao Miyazaki) of the object without the rest, is there a way to do this?

If you need any more information in order to help, please comment. Thanks

Comment: Is that code Java?

Comment: sorry, yes the code is in java

Comment: You don't have to exclusivly use toString to print. If you only want to  print a specific part of your object like director simply create a getter for it and do `System.out.println(myDvd.getDirector());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a get method for the director

```
public String getDirector(){
    return director;
}

System.out.print(myDVD.getDirector());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is Java code, in your `DVD` class, you can override the `toString` method in order to print what you want:

```
public class DVD {

    private String director;
    //more fields and stuff

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return director;
    }

}
```

If you already have a `toString` implementation and need another one, you can add another method to get the director:

```
public String getDirector(){
    return director;
}
```

and print it:

```
System.out.print(myDVD.getDirector());
```

Or you may want a method to do the printing itself:

```
public void printDirector() {
    System.out.println(director);
}
```

Comment: Hey Hector, thanks for helping but I already have a toString in DVD to print out the DVD object so it is not printed out the same as the CD objects I am creating, should the toString I'm using be somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me to understand whats happening!

Answer (score 0):

You could make it as simple as writing a new method printDirector() which would do just that, OR...

You could leave the **responsibility** of printing the information to some other class, and make the DVD object **responsible** only for providing its information:

```
public class Movies {
    public class DVD {

        private director;

        public DVD(String director) {
            this.director = director;
        }

        public String getDirector() {
            return director;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... arg) {
        DVD howl = new DVD("Miyazaki");
        String director = howl.getDirector();
        SomePrinterClass.print(director);
    }
}
```

Ultimately that's a design decision, either will produce the same result.